# How to update a running balance column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table by the name of tblInvManager which have Following Columns

Table Name: tblInvManager

```
InvNo | Customer Name | InvAmount   | AllInvTotal
1     |    Cust A     |    50,000   |     50,000    
2     |    Cust A     |    15,000   |     65,000    
3     |    Cust A     |    25,000   |     90,000    
4     |    Cust A     |    40,000   |    130,000    
5     |    Cust B     |    10,000   |     10,000        
6     |    Cust B     |    35,000   |     45,000        
7     |    Cust B     |    80,000   |    125,000        
8     |    Cust C     |    12,000   |     12,000        
9     |    Cust C     |    18,000   |     30,000
```

For example If value of Invoice Number:1 in the above table is updated from 50,000 to 25,000, I want to update the AllInvTotal Columns As per the changes 
so my new table after the update of Invoice Amount will be as Follow:

**Expected Result**

```
InvNo | Customer Name | InvAmount   | AllInvTotal
1     |    Cust A     |    25,000   |     25,000    
2     |    Cust A     |    15,000   |     40,000    
3     |    Cust A     |    25,000   |     65,000    
4     |    Cust A     |    40,000   |    105,000    
5     |    Cust B     |    10,000   |     10,000        
6     |    Cust B     |    35,000   |     45,000        
7     |    Cust B     |    80,000   |    125,000        
8     |    Cust C     |    12,000   |     12,000        
9     |    Cust C     |    18,000   |     30,000
```

I have made Following Query but i am not able to do so. Can Someome Please help me:

```
DECLARE @Inv_No VARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @LCRef VARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @InvTotal DECIMAL(18,6)  
DECLARE @AllInvTotal DECIMAL(18,6)  

SET @AllInvTotal = 0  

DECLARE InvManagerCursor CURSOR  
FOR SELECT InvNo_InvMan, LCRef_InvMan, InvAmt_InvMan FROM tblInvManager  
FOR UPDATE OF AllInv_InvMan  
OPEN InvManagerCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM InvManagerCursor INTO @InvNo, @LCRef, @InvTotal  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

SET @AllInvTotal += @InvTotal  

Update tblInvManager   
SET AllInv_InvMan = @AllInvTotal  
WHERE CURRENT OF InvManagerCursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM InvManagerCursor INTO @InvNo, @LCRef, @InvTotal  
END  
CLOSE InvManagerCursor  
DEALLOCATE InvManagerCursor
```

Please advise

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. If you have tried anything show your code.

Comment: You should really just write transactions and calculate values at a point in time as needed rather than try to constantly update totals.

Comment: I would advise against a running total column. I can't imagine a single scenario where you would ever need it and not be able to calculate it on the fly.

Comment: As TyCobb mentioned, do you actually need a running total column stored in the database? could you just calculate it on the fly after you get your result sets locally? (Also, you have no `order by` in your query so there is no way to guarantee that the order of the items processed will stay the same)

Comment: Yes I do need this column because i want to show in my datagridview in my application in c#, because all my datagridview is being populated by this table in my application. If i will not have this column in my table than how am i going to show running balance column in my dataridview. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with another query.
Here I will call the Table just "table" since you didn't give us the name.
After every update like:

```
UPDATE table SET inv_amt = 6000 WHERE Inv_no = 2
```

You will have to use the following query:

```
UPDATE table SET totalcustinv = 
  (
    SELECT sum(inv_amt)
    FROM table as secondTable
    WHERE table .Inv_no >= secondTable.Inv_no
  )
```

This query should set the totalcustinv of every row to the sum of inv_amt of all rows with lower or equal Inv_no as the current row.

Of course, for it to work, Inv_no has to be comparable numerically. Since you wrote a dot after every Inv_no i am afraid it's a TEXT and not easily numerically comparable. Since this post should answer your question I will not say how to convert a TEXT into INT.

Another thing: I am not sure if it will work on your SQL-Database. I tested it on PostgreSQL and it worked perfectly!